# ¿Ingresar varios valores en un mismo input? Ejemplo: varios destinatarios de correo

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo hacer para ingresar varios valores en un mismo input? Por ejemplo, si quiero enviar una notificación por email a varios destinatarios, usando PHP, Javascript, etc., en el framework Yii?

En el un formulario (no HTML) tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function createAlert(){        
    $id = $_POST['idAlert'];
    $alertModel = Model_Email::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($alertModel != NULL){
        $alertModel->email = $this->email;
        $alertModel->id_search = $this->id_search;
        $alertModel->time_of_recurrence_unit = $this->time_of_recurrence_unit;
        $alertModel->date_start = $this->date_start;
        $alertModel->id_preference = $this->id_preference;
        $alertModel->status = 'ENABLED';
        $alertModel->save();
    }
    else{
    $emailModel = new Model_Email();
    $emailModel->email = $this->email;
    $emailModel->id_search = $this->id_search;
    $emailModel->time_of_recurrence_unit = $this->time_of_recurrence_unit;
    $emailModel->date_start = $this->date_start;
    $emailModel->id_preference = $this->id_preference;
    $emailModel->status = 'ENABLED';
    if($emailModel->validate() && $emailModel->save()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
        }
    }          
}
```

Lo que crea una notificación que será enviada al usuario y en caso de que ya exista dicha notificación la va a modificar.

Mientras tanto, en el Controller tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function actionSave(){
    if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){            
        $emailModel = new Form_search_email_notification();            
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'email-form'){
            echo CActiveRecord::validate($emailModel);                
            Yii::app()->end;
        }            
        if(isset($_POST['Form_search_email_notification'])){                    
            $emailModel->email = $_POST['Form_search_email_notification']['email'];
            $emailModel->id_search = $_POST['Form_search_email_notification']['id_search_combo'];
            $emailModel->id_preference = $_POST['Form_search_email_notification']['id_preference'];
            $emailModel->time_of_recurrence_unit = $_POST['Form_search_email_notification']['time_of_recurrence_unit'];                
            if($emailModel->validate() && $emailModel->createAlert()){
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Notificación creada');
                $this->redirect('/alert/list');                    
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('alert/list'));
    }
}
```

Agradezco de antemano si alguien puede ayudarme, que conste que el código lo puse solo para mostrar lo que hago, lo que quiero saber es como poder aplicarlo para varios valores al mismo tiempo, o sea, varios destinatarios en éste caso.

Ah, por cierto, la idea sería ingresar un destinatario, presionar enter y poder ingresar otro y así sucesivamente, algo así como cuando ponen tags en algunos sitios.

Answer (score 1):

Existe una extensión para yii2 de kartik de multiple select
Hace lo que quieres y al hacer el envío te lo envía en un array, ya solo tu tendrías que manejar la información para que con los datos se pueda hacer lo que desees desde el lado del backend

https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input

si eres nuevo en yii2 te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a todas las extensiones de kartik y dos amigos, tienen muy buenas que te facilitarán muchas cosas.

kartik: 
http://demos.krajee.com/

dos amigos:
https://www.2amigos.us/open-source

Comment: Hola, primero que nada gracias por comentar, parece ser útil eso que me pasaste pero lamentablemente no estoy usando Yii2, se ve que cuando agregué el tag puse ese sin querer.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes separar los correos electrónicos con un punto y coma, por ejemplo. Si tuvieras algún filtro de caracteres sobre el campo antes de recuperar su valor deberías desactivarlo y filtrar los emails una vez separados.

Al recoger el contenido del input en el servidor tienes un string con todas las direcciones, separadas por punto y coma (o el que usarás), las separas y las válidas y haces lo que tengas que hacer con ellas.

Para lo que quieres hacer, de añadir cada email a un input y que se guarde en una lista con el enter, para después añadir otro, usaría JS. Se va concatenando en un string que puedes mostrar en un elemento, por ejemplo de tipo párrafo a la vez que guardas este string en un input tipo hidden que sera de donde recojas los datos al enviarlo al servidor.